# Geolocalised data on agriculture - harvested land, type of crop

Tags: data-request, agriculture, spatial-economics

I am looking for data on agricultural land use, in particular for Southeast Asia, in particular for harvested land and type of (main crop) at a local level. Ideally the data would be presented as a grid.
[PRIO-GRID](https://grid.prio.org/#/) is almost perfect *but* is quite old (2000 for type of crop, and 2010 for harvested land).